# Why does Jest sometimes prints "pretty" error messages with line pointers, and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I have jest 27 installed, and I see that sometimes I get pretty error messages like this (with visual pointer to the failing line):
[image]

And sometimes it prints the errors like this (plain error, without pointer):
[image]

I am trying to understand why it happens, can someone help me with that?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the relevant content/code of the second test.

Comment: but the question is more general than some specific tests implementation. I am asking what can affect those print. maybe it's the stack trace limit?

Comment: Or may be the test is failing because the test is broken and failing in a different way. Without seeing it, we're having to make an assumption that you haven't missed something. Do repeated runs result in consistent output or are there differences? If it's consistent then it may be your code - if not it may be Jest.

Comment: the test is constantly failing, but I am not asking why it's failing, I know why. I am asking why sometimes I see the beautifully parsed error message with the stack trace pointer, and sometimes I just see the failure message. in  both examples it failed because of exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after doing some investigations, it seems like the difference is if the error happens in `node_modules` or not. If the error is thrown within the project's root, jest will print a pretty message with a pointer to the line that caused the error. But if the error happens from within the `node_modules` folder, Jest will print the error message along with the stack trace, without any visual pointers.